# yarn start-https failed with error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, https

I am working on a project that I downloaded, but having trouble setting up and getting the enviroment started.
After yarn install, yarn build, and then yarn start-https, I get this error message:

```
Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at node:internal/tls/secure-context:65:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setCerts (node:internal/tls/secure-context:63:3)
    at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:152:5)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:116:3)
    at Server.setSecureContext (node:_tls_wrap:1344:27)
    at Server (node:_tls_wrap:1203:8)
    at new Server (node:https:69:3)
    at Object.createServer (node:https:105:10)
    at Server.createServer (.../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:677:35)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I am have followed the set for the readMe file... and I tried googling each line of error message but nothing had helped solved this issue of exiting out.

I feel, that I must be missing something... somthing that was not documented in the readme file...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check your package.json file and especially the script file

if you share more references of your start file it will grate to understand more

happy to help you

Comment: your right! I got it fixed by looking at the json file! thank you

Answer (score 0):

This error showing that you have a problem around ssl settings, you have to prepare self-signed SSL Certificate.